# Is my proof correct? (prove whether $f$ is convex or not)

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis

Domain is $\mathbb{R}^{3N}$, i.e., $\mathcal{D}=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{3N}:x_i\in\mathbb{R},~i=1,2,\ldots,3N\}.$

The function $f$ is defined over the domain $\mathcal{D}$ as
$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x_i-x_j)^2 + (x_k-x_l)^2 + (x_m-x_n)^2},$$
where $i,j,k,l,m$, and $n$ are all different numbers and are in $\{1, 2, \ldots, 3N\}$.

I want to decide whether $f(x)$ is a convex function or not over $x$.

---

WLOG, I first fix $i,j,k,l,m,$ and $n$ to $1,4,2,5,3,$ and $6$, i.e., $f(x)$ is converted into
$$f(x) = \sqrt{(x_1-x_4)^2 + (x_2-x_5)^2 + (x_3-x_6)^2}.$$

I ignore $x_7$ to $x_{3N}$ because they are not in $f(x)$.

If I define $y:= (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ and $z := (x_4, x_5, x_6)$, I can represent $f(x)$ as $$f(y,z) = \Vert y-z \Vert. $$

Then, I will prove that
$$f( \theta y + (1-\theta)y', \theta z + (1-\theta)z') \le \theta f(y,z) + (1-\theta) f(y',z').\tag 1\label{1}$$

Actually, I proved this \eqref{1}. If so, $f(x)$ is a convex function.

---

Is the above proof correct and rigorous?

Comment: Just to clarify, you're proving that a *family* of functions are all convex, depending on the choices of $i, j, k, l, m, n$, right?

Comment: @TheoBendit Even if I convert $1, 4, 2, 5, 3$, and $6$ into $i, j, k, l, m,$ and $n$, the equation (1) holds, I think. Is it not enough?

Comment: I just don't understand the question, as $f$ doesn't appear to be a single, well-defined function.

Comment: @TheoBendit I assumed that there are $N$ points in 3-dimensional space. In this case, I want to prove that the distance function between every pair of points is a cnovex function.

Comment: That's more or less what I was asking. So you're also interpreting that $f$ is one of a family of functions. You get the other members of the family by choosing different variables. If this is the case, then yes, all such $f$ are convex, as each can be written as $\|Ax\|$, where $A$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{3N}$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.